# Entry Probability of a Diffusion Process

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_t$ be a $d\geq 3$-dimensional diffusion process solving the SDE
$$
dX_t = b(X_t) dt + \sigma W_t, \qquad X_0 =x \in \mathbb{R}^d
$$
where $\sigma>0$ $b$ smooth and Lipschitz, and let $D$ be the ball about $0\in \mathbb{R}^d$ of radius $\delta>0$.  Are there known (non-trivial) upper estimates on 
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(
X_t \not \in D\, (\forall t \in [0,1]) 
\right).
$$
granted that $x \not \in D$.  Suppose further that $b(x)=0$ iff $x=0$ and that $b$ is "small".

I would expect that such an estimate would depend on $\sigma,\delta$ and the distance of $x$ from $D$...

Comment: Are you making any assumptions regarding the drift $b$ and size $\sigma > 0$? If $0$ is a unique rest point for $b$ and you are willing to take $\sigma > 0$ small, Freidlin-Wentzell theory will give you these estimates asymptotically in $\sigma$. Otherwise, you are probably looking at some Dirichlet problem, though the bounded time interval may make things complicated. Is there a specific dimension $d$ you want (it may help to distinguish between $d=1$, $d=2$ and $d \geq 3$).

Comment: @snar how can similar results be treated if $b$ is replaced by a uniformly lipschitz function depending on a predictable process (such as in a control problem)?

Comment: I presume that 1D results aren't of any interest? Because in 1D this is relatively standard exercise.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines $P( X_t \notin D ) = P( \exists i | X_t^i | > \delta \forall t \in [0,1] ) =  P( \cup X_t^i \cdots ) \leq \sum_i P( | X_t^i | > \delta )$. Then you can probably bound every $P(| X_t^i | > \delta )$ somehow - maybe by changing by Girsanov to ordinary BM, using some bound for hitting time, and then changing probability measure once again? 

I can try to make it into an answer if this approach seems useful to you